# Spark to Flink parallelize method

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to Flink and currently working on convert some of the code example in Spark to Flink.
What is the similar function in Flink for parallelize method in `JavaSparkContext`? I tried to convert the following code:

```java
JavaRDD<Integer> workload = ctx.parallelize(Arrays.asList(init_val), parallel).map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer call(Integer s) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(s * 1000);
        return 0;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink's equivalent of `JavaSparkContext.parallelize()` is `ExecutionEnvironment.fromCollection()`.

So your code snippet should translate to something like:

```java
// get execution environment
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// create data set from collection
DataSet<Integer> input = env.fromCollection(Arrays.asList(init_val));
// apply map function
DataSet<Integer> result = input.map(new MapFunction<Integer, Integer>() {
  @Override
  public Integer map(Integer s) {
    Thread.sleep(s * 1000);
    return 0;
  }
}).setParallelism(parallel); // set parallelism of map function
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `fromCollection` method provided by the `ExecutionEnvironment`.

```java
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataSet<Integer> input = env.fromCollection(inputList);
```